# Programa que pida las notas, las sume y haga la media

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer un programa que pida la nota de prácticas y la nota de teoría y calcule la nota final, la prácita vale un 30% y la teoría un 70%, se necesita un 5 en la teoría y un 5 en la práctica para hacer la media. He hecho el programa así l oque pasa es que si le doy una nota inferior a 5, me suma las notas pero no las múltiplica por los porcentajes, entonces siempre me da las notas como aprobadas.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class notas {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    double notaPracticas=0;

    double notaTeoria=0;

    double notaFinal=0;

    Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduce tu nota de prácticas");

    notaPracticas=teclado.nextDouble();

     if (notaPracticas>=5) {

         notaPracticas=notaPracticas*0.30;

         System.out.println(notaPracticas);

    } else if (notaPracticas<5) {

        System.out.println("Nota incorrecta");

    }

    System.out.println("Introduce tu nota de teoría");

    notaTeoria=teclado.nextDouble();

    if (notaTeoria>=5) {

        notaTeoria=notaTeoria*0.70;

        System.out.println(notaTeoria); 


    }else if (notaTeoria<5)

        System.out.println("Nota incorrecta");

    notaFinal=notaPracticas+notaTeoria;

    System.out.println(notaFinal);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema esta en el mal uso de los if ya que unicamente multiplicara por tus porcentajes si la nota es mayor o igual a 5, si quieres que de todos modos al ingresar una nota lo multiplique por tus porcentajes si o si debes hacer los siguinete:

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
double notaPracticas=0;
double notaTeoria=0;
double notaFinal=0;
Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
```

//nota de practicas

```
System.out.println("Introduce tu nota de prácticas");
notaPracticas=teclado.nextDouble();
notaPracticas=notaPracticas*0.30;
System.out.println(notaPracticas);
```

//nota de teoria

```
System.out.println("Introduce tu nota de teoría");
notaTeoria=teclado.nextDouble();
notaTeoria=notaTeoria*0.70;
```

//nota final

```
notaFinal=notaPracticas+notaTeoria;
System.out.println(notaFinal);
```

//Condicional segun tu criterio print aprobado o no aprobado
}

Answer (score 0):

Basandome en el enunciado que has puesto te he hecho un *pequeño ejemplo* de como lo haría yo. Primero pido las notas, luego compruebo que ninguna sea menor que 5 y si supera la prueba calculo la nota final con la fórmula de `(teo*0.7)+(pra*0.3)`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class notas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double notaPracticas, notaTeoria, notaFinal = 0;
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Pedir datos por consola
        System.out.println("Introduce tu nota de prácticas");
        notaPracticas = teclado.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Introduce tu nota de teoría");
        notaTeoria=teclado.nextDouble();

        //Tratar los datos
        if (notaTeoria < 5)
            System.out.println("Teoría suspensa, no se puede hacer la media")
        else if (notaPracticas < 5) 
            System.out.println("Prácticas suspensas, no se puede hacer la media.");
        else {
            notaFinal = (notaPracticas*0.30)+(notaTeoria*0.70)
            System.out.println("Tú nota final es de: '" + notaFinal + "' ptos.");
        }
    }
}
```

Por otro lado, **respondiendo directamente a tu duda**. Fíjate que si la nota es menor que 5 no pasa por el multiplicador del porcentaje, ya que está dentro del `if(nota >= 5)` así que si quieres que se muestre la nota multiplicada (aunque no parece que sea necesario, ya que no debería hacer media) sácalo fuera.

Otro apunte, ten cuidado con el uso del `if() else if()`, es mejor que utilices el `if() else`. Porque aunque en este caso el funcionamiento sea el mismo, puede que te cause algún quebradero de cabeza en el futuro.

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta